# How to generate all possible variations of a 2 matrix of an enum element in python?

Tags: python, enums, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have an enum:

```
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
   EMTPY = 0
   APPLE = 1
   HONEY = 2
```

I want to feed in 2 values height and width and I want to get every possible variation of a 2D array where each element is a MyEnum.

E.g.

```
def variations(height, width):
    variation = # code
    yield variation

for v in variations(2,2):
    print(v)
    print("---------")
```

will print

```
[
  [EMTPY, EMTPY],
  [EMTPY, EMTPY]
]
---------
[
  [APPLE, EMTPY],
  [EMTPY, EMTPY]
]
---------
[
  [HONEY, EMTPY],
  [EMTPY, EMTPY]
]
---------
[
  [EMTPY, APPLE],
  [EMTPY, EMTPY]
]
...
```

I was looking into combinations and permutations of the itertools library, but every attempt failed, because this task seems more complex than the tutorials in the internet.

Because I will probably have big height and width parameters, I want my variations function to be a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it in two steps:

1. Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate `width*height`-sized permutations with repetition
2. Split the list into rows of a matrix.

---

```
import itertools
def variations(items,width,height):
  for one in itertools.product(items,repeat=width*height):                # step 1
    yield [list(one[i*width:(i+1)*width]) for i in range(height)]         # step 2

for mtx in variations(["EMPTY","APPLE","HONEY"],2,2):
  print(mtx)
```

Will produce all the 81 (3<sup>4</sup>) possible matrices:

> ```
> [['EMPTY', 'EMPTY'], ['EMPTY', 'EMPTY']]
> [['EMPTY', 'EMPTY'], ['EMPTY', 'APPLE']]
> [['EMPTY', 'EMPTY'], ['EMPTY', 'HONEY']]
> [['EMPTY', 'EMPTY'], ['APPLE', 'EMPTY']]
> ...
> [['HONEY', 'HONEY'], ['HONEY', 'APPLE']]
> [['HONEY', 'HONEY'], ['HONEY', 'HONEY']]
> ```